# Retrieve all records by checkbox in jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

Is it possible to retrieve all records by checking a checkbox located on the top of DataTable? I mean that I want to add a checkbox and if the user check it, it pass a parameter (for example bool isAll) to the Controller via AJAX and the records are obtained according to isAll parameter by changing the search query. I look at many different sections on [Offical Documentation](https://datatables.net/) but there is no seem to have this feature. It is something like shown below. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML looks like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="checkAll(this)"></th>
        <th >x</th>
        <th >y</th>
        <th >z</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

I would do something like this to check all 'checkboxes' named myCheckBox:

```
function checkAll(x) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('myCheckBox');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length; i<n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = x.checked;
  }
}
```

Then if you want to send that to your AJAX as a string:

```
function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
    var checkboxesChecked = [];
    for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
     if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        checkboxesChecked.push({"ID":checkboxes[i].value});
     }
    }
    return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : null;
    }
    var checkedBoxes = getCheckedBoxes("cluster_checkbox");
    var data = JSON.stringify(checkedBoxes);
```

Then in your AJAX call the var data with the string:

```
$.ajax({type : "POST",
            url : "/new_custCluster.php",
            data: {'IDs': data},
            }).done(function(result) {
                alert("Success");
            }).fail(function() {
                alert("Failure");
            });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it did not worked. Maybe it is better to simplify it having get just a checkbox value instead of array.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can alter the DataTables layout other than modifying [DataTables Code](//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js)

Comment: Ok, in that case your answer is helpful even if not solved the problem completely. Voted+

Comment: Amigo, Any ide about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571553/jquery-datatable-individual-column-searching-on-table-header) question?